# Как организовать работу продакшн и  демо сайта?

Tags: drupal, svn, git, php, mysql

Мне необходимо, чтобы была синхронизация между двумя сайтами (демо и основным). Не знаю, как сделать синхронизацию БД.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы уверенны, что вам нужна именно полная синхронизация!? Я тоже делаю, все на тесте, а потом ложу в продакшин, но ложу я это вручную, так как в 95% случаях нужна только структура да и процесс контролировать хочется.
2. Если синхронизация полная, и от основного к подчиненному; то можно через mysqldump + выполнение (через mysql < dat.sql) по крону;
3. Более менее качественно сложную синхронизацию структуры и данных умеют делать программки от navicat (Navicat for MySQL или Navicat Premium). Но о полной автоматике речи здесь не идет.

Answer (score 1):

Создать группу для аккаунтов с ограниченными правами специально для демо версии.

Всех пользователей, кто должен работать с демо, держать в этой группе.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, нужны ли разные базы?
Можно на поддомене beta держать бета-версию файлов, а база общая останется, при крайней необходимости создавать таблицы с beta-префиксом.